# htaccess URL rewrite for domain.com.php page format?

Tags: .htaccess

I understand how to use Rewrite rules in .htaccess to strip out the .php file extension, but this only works if the filename is convential, i.e. 'page.php'.

I have a load of pages that are in this format 'domain.com.php' or 'domain.co.uk.php', and am trying to get them to appear after Rewrite as /domain.com. For example: example.com/stackoverflow.com, where the filename is actually *stackoverflow.com.php*

I'm using this code from another Stackoverflow question:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I've tried a few ideas, but none work:

```
RewriteEngine On
...
RewriteRule (.*)(.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use these rules for `.php` extension hiding:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```